# Recent Release of crate io with jar details

Tags: io, crate

Hi Could you give me the following details 
 1.What is the latest release of crate io  with supported jar files
1.crate io jar (version) 
2 .crate jdbc jar( version)

Answer (score 0):

Crate.IO is hosting their jar files on Bintray.

You can find the available jars and their versions [here](https://bintray.com/crate/crate/).

More detailed: [crate](https://bintray.com/crate/crate/crate/view), [jdbc](https://bintray.com/crate/crate/crate-jdbc/view)